# C++ arrays inside struct, how to deal with them?

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct Node 
{
    double linkCost[8];
    int val;
    Node *prevNode;
}
nodeBuf = new Node();
```

I can access Node.val by doing:

```
nodeBuf->val
```

but linkCost doesn't work that way. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: `linkCost doesn't work that way`. Please example. `nodeBuf->linkCost[0] = 0` is perfectly correct.

Comment: This code won’t compile. Please post the real code. Furthermore, your question isn’t clear but that is probably a consequence of the incomplete code.

Comment: linkCost does work that way.  It sounds like you're doing something illegal with `nodeBuf->linkCost`, but you'll need to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Node 
{
    double linkCost[8];
    int val;
    Node *prevNode;
}
```

try to declare it like that for better alignment :

```
struct Node 
{

    int val;
    Node *prevNode;
   double linkCost[8];
}


nodeBuf = new Node();
nodeBuf->linkcost[i] = 3.14; //set the i element. to pi
```

Comment: Is that alignment good for 64 bit? `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes on my x86_64 here (GCC 4.7, Linux), so the pointer will still not be aligned to 8 bytes.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid padding, you definitely want the `Node*` before the `int`. Rule of thumb is to list the members in decreasing order of alignment requirement. Of course that's implementation-dependent, but you're unlikely to hit an implementation on which `int` is more aligned than a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
nodeBuf->linkCost[index] = value
```